# Comparing two files for similarities, not the commonly asked question

Tags: python, loops, file, text, iteration

My problem: I have two .txt files, I would like to use one of the files as a guide for the filtering the second file. Appending the similarities to a new .txt file 3.

For example:
File 1: A list of names
File 2: A list of names and email addressess.

If any name from file 1 is not found in any line(s) in file 2, delete that line and append the matching line to a new .txt file.

Obviously I have googled this question every which way I could word it, and have even found a web application that does exactly this, however it is not capable of handling the size files I need. I have attempted to write a python script for doing this (I am fairly new to programming), from what i have read im sure it would be easier using something like NumPy which I do not know. I just need a nudge in the right direction, this is just slightly outside of my skill set. I am capable of writing a script for web scraping using regex and other basic beginning stuff like that, but this is something I really need to solve quickly and cannot seem to find a solution that truly fits the problem elsewhere. Every other solution to similarly asked questions is referring to a single string, or showing differences not similarities.

This is my attempt, which is obviously incorrect:

```
    file1 = input("Input file 1: ")
    file2 = input("Input file 2: ")
            
    with open("file1.txt", r) as f1:
        lines1 = f1.read.splitlines()
        names = file1.split(";")[0]
        emails = file1.split(";")[1]
    with open("file2.txt", r) as f2:
        lines2 = f2.read.splitlines()
            
        newfile = open("newfile", w)
            
    for names in lines2:
        strip(line)
        newfile.write(line)
```

I would really appreciate some advice or a nudge in the correct direction. Thank you !

File sample:

```
file 1:
1.ustrading@uste-miami.com  
2.georgeanddonna@reagan.com  
3.sbright@carltonrochell.com  
4.mary@roadrunnerss.com  

File 2:  
1.Jack Young;ustrading@uste-miami.com  
2.George Russel;georgeanddonna@reagan.com  
3.Susan Shields;sbright@carltonrochell.com  
4.Mary Cartwright;mary@roadrunnerss.com  
5.Heather Carter;heatherc@bridgerkitchens.com  
6.Denise Black;dd@genereux.us  
7.Tanner Tennebaum;ctannenbaum@chefswithaltitude.com  
8.John Grable;jgrable@johngrable.com  
9.Connor Hawk;cmhworld@rof.net
```

So I am looking to parse the first 4 Name;Email lines in file 2 using file 1 as the source of interesting data.

Comment: Of course, you can do this in basic Python. But it sounds like a good job for `pandas`. How big are these files? And you should provide example input data and output data that reflect how exactly these txt files are constructed.

Comment: One is a few mb tops, this would be the file containing only the values that I would like to find in the larger file. The other would be a few hundred mb tops.

Comment: Apologies, I was trying to, I didnt realize I could, for some reason I had it in my head I needed to be a member for longer before I could edit a post. And then I had some issues with the syntax checking function thinking my lists were code... but I fixed it and its up there

Comment: This is exactly how the text file entries look like, yes? No header (like "ID, name, email"), no spaces between the numbers, names, emails? I am asking because this may influence the data parsing.

Comment: Yes, no header and no space, the delim is a ;

Comment: I find your * If any name from file 1... * sentence a bit vague.  Perhaps just showing us your desired output files would be clearer.

Answer (score 2):

My assumptions:

- file1.txt contains one email address per line and nothing but that.
- file2.txt contains one name and one email per line, separated by a semicolon
- you are looking for matches between the two datasets

```
# first, read in the smaller set of the entries we are interested in finding
with open("file1.txt") as file1:
  # strip them of any leading or trailing whitespace (e.g. newlines) and empty lines
  needles = [line.strip() for line in file1.readlines()]
  needles = set(filter(bool, needles))

# now open the haystack file2 and the output file3
with open("file2.txt") as file2, open("file3.txt", "w") as file3:
  # we iterate line by line to not fill up the memory too much
  for line in file2:
    # strip any whitespace from the line
    line = line.strip()
    # ...and skip over empty lines
    if not line: continue
    # we assume each line contains exactly one semicolon that separates name from email
    name, email = line.split(";")
    # does the email match any of the ones we are looking for?
    if email in needles:
      # then format the line correctly and write it to the output file
      file3.write("{};{}\n".format(name, email))
```

Contents of the input files:

file1.txt

```
ustrading@uste-miami.com  
georgeanddonna@reagan.com  
sbright@carltonrochell.com  
mary@roadrunnerss.com
```

file2.txt

```
Jack Young;ustrading@uste-miami.com  
George Russel;georgeanddonna@reagan.com  
Susan Shields;sbright@carltonrochell.com  
Mary Cartwright;mary@roadrunnerss.com  
Heather Carter;heatherc@bridgerkitchens.com  
Denise Black;dd@genereux.us  
Tanner Tennebaum;ctannenbaum@chefswithaltitude.com  
John Grable;jgrable@johngrable.com  
Connor Hawk;cmhworld@rof.net
```

contents of file3.txt after running the script:

```
Jack Young;ustrading@uste-miami.com
George Russel;georgeanddonna@reagan.com
Susan Shields;sbright@carltonrochell.com
Mary Cartwright;mary@roadrunnerss.com
```